# Recargar combobox C#

Tags: c#

Buen día,

Planteo mi problema, tengo un combobox que se carga en el inicio del load del formulario, el combobox a medida que se va creando un cliente, se debe ir recargando para mostrar la información nueva,¿Cuál es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Adjunto mi codigo:

```
       Cls_general myCls_general = new cls_general();

        myCls_general.conexion_mssql("2");

        strSQL = " select IdContacto,fld_Nomb_Apel_Razon_Social   " +
                 "   from bd_gestion_de_tareas_config.dbo.vi_list_contactos " +
                 " where IdContacto NOT IN (SELECT IdContacto FROM gestionDeTareas.dbo.Clientes) " +
                 " Order by fld_Nomb_Apel_Razon_Social ASC ";

        myCboContactoDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myCls_general.myConnection);
        myCboContactoDataSet = new DataSet();
        myCboContactoDataAdapter.Fill(myCboContactoDataSet, "vi_list_contactos");




        cbo_contacto_cliente.DataSource = myCboContactoDataSet.Tables["vi_list_contactos"];
        cbo_contacto_cliente.DisplayMember = "fld_Nomb_Apel_Razon_Social";
        cbo_contacto_cliente.ValueMember = "IdContacto";

        myCboContactoDataAdapter.Dispose();
        myCboContactoDataSet.Dispose();

        myCls_general.cerrar_conexion();
```

Comment: ¿Cómo creas los clientes? Cada vez que crees uno deberás añadirlo al comboBox mediante comboBox.Add(cliente)

Comment: Los clientes los cargo en un formulario. El objetivo de la pregunta, es como recargar el combobox sin salir y volver a entrar al form para ver los cambios actualizados.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deberás hacer es en el método que añades un cliente volver a asignarle el dataSource, es decir, repetir tu código en el botón guardar cliente

```
  Cls_general myCls_general = new cls_general();

    myCls_general.conexion_mssql("2");

    strSQL = " select IdContacto,fld_Nomb_Apel_Razon_Social   " +
             "   from bd_gestion_de_tareas_config.dbo.vi_list_contactos " +
             " where IdContacto NOT IN (SELECT IdContacto FROM gestionDeTareas.dbo.Clientes) " +
             " Order by fld_Nomb_Apel_Razon_Social ASC ";

    myCboContactoDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myCls_general.myConnection);
    myCboContactoDataSet = new DataSet();
    myCboContactoDataAdapter.Fill(myCboContactoDataSet, "vi_list_contactos");




    cbo_contacto_cliente.DataSource = myCboContactoDataSet.Tables["vi_list_contactos"];
    cbo_contacto_cliente.DisplayMember = "fld_Nomb_Apel_Razon_Social";
    cbo_contacto_cliente.ValueMember = "IdContacto";

    myCboContactoDataAdapter.Dispose();
    myCboContactoDataSet.Dispose();

    myCls_general.cerrar_conexion();
```

De esta manera cada vez que añades un cliente le vuelves a asignar los clientes (con el cliente nuevo ya creado).

Comment: Perfecto! Te hago una ultima consulta y disculpa la molestia.

En ese mismo combobox, cuando lo voy a usar para cargar algunas pestañas del formulario, necesito excluir el cliente que en ese momento estoy posicionado, es decir, que a través del ID de cliente, me lo excluya en ese momento del combo.

Eso lo se hacer, pero el problema que tengo, es que la carga del combobox lo tengo con el Load del formulario y obviamente al ser nulo el ID al inicio del form me salta un error, como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Nada! No olvides marcar como respondida la respuesta si ha resuelto tu duda. Puedes abrir una nueva pregunta con el código que lo excluyes y el error que te da?

Comment: Lo que me indicaste, me da el siguiente error: +  $exception {"No se puede modificar la colección Items cuando está establecida la propiedad DataSource."} System.ArgumentException

Comment: Pero cuándo te la da? Cuándo añades un cliente?

Comment: Si, lo añadí en el botón guardar de mi form, para que cuando el cliente se le asigne un ID, desaparezca del combobox (en ese momento es donde se debe actualizar el combobox para no mostrar nuevamente ese contacto.)

Comment: Añade el datasource de nuevo simplemente en el botón, si esta actualizado con el cliente nuevo, debería actualizarse el comboBox

Comment: Tras los pasos que me indicaste, sigue sin actualizarse el combobox.

Comment: y el dataset está actualizado?

Comment: Como lo puedo verificar?

Comment: si no lo as añadido lo tendras que añadir, edito la respuesta

Comment: El datasource lo igualo a null?

cbo_contacto_cliente.DataSource = null;
myCboContactoDataSet.Tables["vi_list_contactos"];

Comment: No , repite tu código otra vez en el botón guardar.

Comment: Nada, tras añadir:

cbo_accionistas.DataSource = myCboAccionistasDataSet.Tables["vi_listado_contactos"];

Sigue sin actualizarse.

Comment: por que lo que no tienes actualizado es el dataSet, actualizalo de nuevo como lo haces al iniciar el form pero en el botón guardar y tiene que funcionarte al igual que cuando inicias la aplicación

Comment: Vuelvo a cargar todo el cargar_cbo_accionista();... perdón, pero no entiendo mucho, me manejo con lo basico.

Comment: Asigna todo el código con el que cargas los comboBox en el load, en el botón guardar.

Comment: Perfecto, así si funciona. En tal caso, hacerlo así, no sobrecarga el código? Mi idea es aprender a hacer toda la programación de la manera más limpia y optimizada posible.

Comment: Si quieres lo que puedes hacer es extraer el metodo, creando uno como public void rellenarComboBox(){  tu funcion }, y luego le llamas desde el load y desde el boton guardar  así : rellenarComboBox(), y asi ahorras código y lo llamas desde donde lo necesites. No olvides marcar la respuesta como respondida si resolvió tu pregunta.